# get parents category name and content

Tags: wordpress

how can i get my parent category info in my category page. let me explain details.

say like i have  category like

```
Photos
  Gallery one
  Gallery Two
  Gallery Three
```

i used feature category image plugins also.. so my menu is photos. so when i will click photos it who all parent category name and featured image

feature image shortcode is `[FeaturedImagesCat taxonomy='category' columns='3']`

i think i can get feature image easily but main thing how to show parent category name with permalink

```
    <?php

get_header(); ?>


    <h1><?php if (is_category()) { single_cat_title(); } ?></h1>

   <?php
$category = get_the_category();
$parent = get_cat_name($category[0]->category_parent);
if (!empty($parent)) {
echo '&raquo; ' . $parent;
} else {
echo '&raquo; ' . $category[0]->cat_name;
}
?>



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: can you review what you are asking? its not clear what you want to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
//Get all terms in current category
$term =  $wp_query->queried_object;
```

Now you can get the parent category ID

```
$parentId = $term->parent;
```

Then you can get the description:

```
echo category_description( $parentId );
```

full code:

```
//Get all terms in current category
$term =  $wp_query->queried_object;

//parent id
$parentId = $term->parent;

if($parentId == 0){
   echo category_description();
}else{
   echo category_description( $parentId );
}
```